# Simple fraction question $\frac{5}{x+5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm in the Geometry class and it's been a while since I took math, I realized I had tons of gaps in fractions.
I was really confused by these two:

$$\frac{5}{x+5}$$ Why doesn't $\frac{5}{5}$ turn into 1, so that we have $\frac{5}{x}$ remaining?
Also at $$\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$$
What am I doing wrong here by canceling the 1's, having x to the neg 1 power, using the reciprocal to get $\frac{1}{x^1}$?

Comment: What did you try? Take, say, $x=2$ and look what happens.

Comment: What is $\frac{5}{5+5}$?

Comment: Fractions are a multiplicative structure. You cancel things by dividing (or multiplying) the _entire_ numerator, at once, and the _entire_ denominator, at once, with the same thing. Not by subtracting or adding things from the numerator and the denominator, and not by dividing _parts_ of the numerator or denominator by anything.

Comment: You can add, subtract , multiply and divide. If you divide top and bottom of your fraction by 5 you get $$\frac{1}{\frac{x}{5}+1}$$. Always ask yourself, "am I adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\frac{5}{x+5}$$ Why doesn't $\frac{5}{5}$ turn into 1, so that we have $\frac{5}{x}$ remaining?

Because fractions don't work like that. You can *split the numerator*:
$$\color{green}{\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}}$$
but not the denominator:
$$\color{red}{\frac{a}{b+c} \ne \frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}}$$
Try it with a few numerical examples to convince yourself of this.

---

> Also at $$\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$$
>   What am I doing wrong here by canceling the 1's, having x to the neg 1 power, using the reciprocal to get $\frac{1}{x^1}$?

You cannot cancel the 1's because in a fraction, you can only cancel (common) **factors**, not (common) **terms**; so:
$$\color{green}{\frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}}$$
but you can't do:
$$\color{red}{\frac{a+c}{b+c} \ne \frac{a}{b}}$$
In fact, 'cancelling' is what we say when we actually, more formally, mean that we are dividing (or multiplying) numerator and denominator by the same (non-zero) number.

Comment: Thank you Stack! :) Hey, do you mind explaining to me my second example? $\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$? Is there a way to solve this without factoring?

Comment: @oijioj I added a part. Note that there is nothing to _solve_, but if you want to _simplify_ that fraction, (factoring and) dividing by $x-1$ would be the way to go.

Comment: Stack, it's me again^^ So I was getting to it now and well I factor the $x^2 -1$ into $(x-1)(x+1)$ but why can I now cancel $x-1$? Maybe I didn't quite understand the concept of cancelling yet, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @oijioj Because now the fraction has a common **factor** (x-1) in the numerator and denominator (it is the "c" in the green $\color{green}{\tfrac{ac}{bc}}$) so you can divide numerator and denominator by this factor; or in other words: 'cancel' the common factor.

Comment: I see now, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think, more fundamentally, you need to recognise the invisible brackets in fractions.

$$\frac{5}{x+5} = (5) \div (x+5)$$

As **BIMDAS** says (or whatever order of operations acronym you use), do your brackets before your division. And clearly, you can't divide $5$ by $x+5$. Hence, you can't simplify it like you did.

Answer (score 0):

So your way would result in, say:
$$\frac13=\frac{5}{10+5}=\frac5{10}=\frac12.$$